# Tracking click control's path on the Android APP

Tags: android

I want to develop a tracking library (`tracking.jar`). This jar should track the clicked control's path in an Android app. When we click a button, this jar should log the button's UI path.

For example, given the following UI:

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <TextView></TextView>
    <LinearLayout>
        <Button></Button>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

- when we click the Button, it should log `RelativeLayout/LinearLayout/Button`;
- when we click the TextView, it should log `RelativeLayout/TextView`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution, but is not perfect. AccessibilityService can tracking click, but you need to manually open the Accessibility Service.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService.html

```
 public class SampleAccessibilityService extends AccessibilityService {

 public String getParentView(AccessibilityNodeInfo node){
    return node != null ? node.getClassName() + "/" + getParentView(node.getParent()) : "";
}

@Override
public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent accessibilityEvent) {
    Log.e(tag,"click path is:" + getParentView(accessibilityEvent.getSource()));
    }
 }
```